# KIVY Refresh Image on Kivy Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy and python file below. I am trying to update the source of an image in the kivy file "settings_screen" by clicking on change picture button but the image remains the same. What can i do so that the source of the image actually changes changing the image? It might be that the settings_screen does not refresh the string indicating the source

python file

"""

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/".join(x for x in __file__.split("/") 
[:-1]))
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import requests
import json
from workoutbanner import WorkoutBanner
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, 
StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == 'ios':
   from pyobjus import autoclass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
     pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,Image):
     pass

class SigninScreen(Screen):
     pass

class MealofthedayScreen(Screen):
     pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
     pass


class MainApp(App):
    native_image_picker = ObjectProperty(None)
    image_path = StringProperty("")
    my_user_id = 'user1'
    user_table = "users"
    activity_table = "activities"
    user_id = StringProperty('user1')
    get_users = requests.get("https://uniquedatabase- 
    c4647-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + user_table + 
    ".json")
    data_get_users = 
                  json.loads(get_users.content.decode())
    image_source_profile = 
               str(data_get_users[my_user_id] 
               ['picture'])

    def build(self):
        GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return GUI 

    def on_start(self):
        #Query database data
        if platform == 'ios':
              self.native_image_picker = 
           autoclass("NativeImagePicker").alloc().init()
        result_users = 
             requests.get("https://uniquedatabase-c4647- 
             default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + 
             self.user_table + ".json")
        result_activities = 
             requests.get("https://uniquedatabase-c4647- 
             default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + 
             self.activity_table + ".json")
        data_users = 
             json.loads(result_users.content.decode())
        data_activities = 
          json.loads(result_activities.content.decode())
    
        streak_label = 
        self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['streak_label']
        streak_label.text = 
        str(data_users[self.my_user_id]['streak'])
    
        banner_grid = 
        self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['banner_grid']
        for workouts in data_activities.values():
                 W = 
                   WorkoutBanner(user=workouts['user'],
                   date=workouts['date'],
                   firstName=workouts['firstName']
                 ,typeWorkout=workouts['typeOfWorkout'],
              lenghtWorkout=workouts['lenghtOfWorkout'])
                 banner_grid.add_widget(W)
        
      def update(self):
           print("Updating image...")

           folder = "/".join(x for x in 
                    self.user_data_dir.split("/")[:-1])
           image_path = folder + "/" + "cached.png"
           self.image_source_profile = image_path
        
      def pick_image(self):
          if platform == 'ios':
           self.native_image_picker.displayImagePicker() 
    
          #Fill HomeScreen feed
      def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
    
    MainApp().run()
```

"""

Kivy file

"""

```
#: import get_profile_picture 
firebase_functions.get_profile_picture

<SettingsScreen>:

  GridLayout:
    columns: 1
    rows: 4
    Image:
        source: app.image_source_profile
        size_hint: 1,1
        pos_hint: {'top': 1,'right': 0}
    Button:
        text: 'Change picture'
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1,1,0,1
        on_release:
            app.pick_image()
            app.update()
    Button:
        text: 'Change password'
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1,1,0,1
        font_size: 13
    Button:
        text: 'Change text color'
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1,1,0,1
        font_size: 13
```

"""

Comment: If you define your `image_source_profile` as a `StringProperty`, it should update automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your image_source_profile as a StringProperty, it should update automatically. Try replacing:

```
image_source_profile = 
           str(data_get_users[my_user_id] 
           ['picture'])
```

with:

```
image_source_profile = 
           StringProperty(str(data_get_users[my_user_id] 
           ['picture']))
```